# Finding the duration of time spent at work excluding multi ins and outs

Tags: date, excel, spreadsheet, vba

I have an excel sheet with thousands of records for employee ins and outs during work hours. I want to find the duration of time the employee spent at work. I need a way to calculate the difference between the first in and last out and ignoring records in between them. 
The sheet look something like this

```
Employee       In                 out
   A       1-Jan 6:30            1-Jan 9:30
   A       1-Jan 9:50            1-Jan 4:30
   A       1-Jan 4:40            1-Jan 5:30
   A       2-Jan 6:32            2-Jan 10:30
   A       2-Jan 11:00           2-Jan 4:25
   B           .                   .
   .
   .           .                   .
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 9:50->4:30, 11:00->4:25? This data makes no sense as employees leave before enter!!!

Comment: 9:50 AM 4:30 PM. And that was a random example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is in columns A, B and C, and you want the duration for employee `A` in column D1, this formula will do it:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A5="A",C1:C5))-MIN(IF(A1:A5="A",B1:B5))
```

After you enter the formula into the cell, instead of pressing `Enter` to escape the cursor, you need to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to make it work.

I hope this helps?

Edit: I did not assume any headers, so data starts at row 1.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sneaky way by using `VLOOKUP` - The data will have to be sorted for this to work.

To find the start time, it's an easy `=VLOOKUP("A",A2:C999,2,FALSE)`
To find the end time, we have to find the last **"A"** record, and we do this by searching for a tiny bit more than "A": `=VLOOKUP("A!",A2:C999,3,TRUE)`
Note the TRUE in the VLOOKUP so it will return the next largest value that is less than what we search for, so it will return the *last* "A"

subtract one from the other, and we have the equation:

```
=VLOOKUP("A!",A2:C999,3,TRUE)-VLOOKUP("A",A2:C999,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For employ 'A', assuming your columns are `A:A` to `C:C` (and dates are recognized as such, not text):

```
= SUMIF(A:A; "A"; C:C) - SUMIF(A:A; "A"; B:B)
```